# Better way to put several shapes in the right places

Tags: css, position, css-position

I was trying to make a crystal bar by using CSS. 
[image: crystal bar]
[Here is a JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/dememoqequ/1/edit?html,css,output)

The 3 shapes would be misplaced according to the different resolution of display. I've met so many times of putting shapes in the right places. Is there a better way to manipulate the place of shapes?

EDIT:
My second method ([another JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/xizedoqafa/1/edit?html,css,output)) to make a div to group shapes together. But this is not working well, either. (cannot centre the shapes nor rotate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you had in mind?

http://jsfiddle.net/j5gk9srn/

```
<div class="bar"></div>

body {
  background: #111;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #aef;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.bar:before, .bar:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
.bar:before {
  top: -10px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #aef;
}
.bar:after {
  bottom: -10px;
  border-top: 10px solid #aef;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sean! That's what I want! I'll trying use pseudo elements in the future. So why use "content: ' '; "? We need to use no content to show the shape?

Comment: You need to declare content for the before/after pseudo elements.  Otherwise there is nothing there to exist in the dom.